# nested elements in react communication

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly new to react and I wondered what's the correct way of passing handlers from top level element to deeply nested child.
I found myself moving handlers through intermediate children props but if feels like pipelining it is not the right solution.
I guess there's better way to do so.
Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can consider is to use `redux` and `react-redux`'s `connect` to "connect" your deeply nested child components to a store.

```
/* your deeply nested child */
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { actionCreator1, actionCreator2 } from './path/to/actionCreators';

@connect(
  (state) => ({
    prop1: state.path.to.prop1,
    prop2: state.path.to.prop2
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    onBtnClick: e => dispatch(actionCreator1()),
    onSomethingChange: e => dispatch(actionCreator2(e.target.value))
  })
)
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.props.prop1}
          onChange={this.props.onSomethingChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.props.onBtnClick}>submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and in your root component:

```
import store from './path/to/reduxStore';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

class RootComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <Provider store={store}>
      <YourParentComponent />
    </Provider>
  }
}
```

More detailed example is here [Usage with React](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html)